# Adding Single Line to File with SaltStack

Tags: centos6, saltstack

I would like to add the following lines to all /etc/sudoers files across my environment:

```
# Administrators LDAP Group
%Administrators   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

However, each server has a different /etc/sudoers file, and sourcing them all from one location would be impractical.

**Is there a way in Salt to ensure a single line (or group of lines) exists in a file, rather than managing that whole file?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably looking for [file.append](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.append).

File.append searches the whole file and if it is unable to find your text, it will append it to the end of the file. I am assuming that you don't know of any common text structures in you /etc/sudoers file so you won't be able to use something like file.sed to replace some text.

Sample Code:

```
/etc/sudoers:
  file.append:
    - text: 
      - "# Administrators LDAP Group"
      - "%Administrators   ALL=(ALL)       ALL"
```

NOTE: You should probably test the sample code before you use it.

Comment: That was perfect!  In my case I used a `- source` file rather than `- text`, but the principal is the same.

Comment: For somwhat more sophisticated operations inside unmanaged files, I found `file.blockreplace` useful;  [this blog](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/saltstack-manage-entries-in-unmanaged-files-with-file-blockreplace) has a good tutorial